# Parsing JSON webservice result android

Tags: android, json, jsonresult

This is part of an AsyncTask that calls a web service that returns a JSON result.  As you can see I hard coded the actual JSON return object.  This was pulled directly from the error I got that specified it could not create the JSON object from the string object I was passing in, which is the variable result.  That error occured when it hit `new JSONObject(result)` in the `ParseResults` method.  Why would hard coding the exact string work but not the string being passed in?

```
@Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                result = "{\"Response\":{\"ReturnCode\":200,\"ReturnMessage\":\"Information Successfully Retrieved\",\"ReturnData\":null,\"ReturnClass\":{\"PRO_ID\":\"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111\",\"PRO_FirstName\":\"SILVER\",\"PRO_LastName\":\"HIYO\"},\"FriendlyErrorMessage\":null}}";
                JSONObject jsonObject = new ApiMethods().ParseResult(result);
```

ParseResults method snippet.

```
public JSONObject ParseResult(String result) throws JSONException
    {
        JSONObject returnedObject = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Also below, as i stated in a comment to another user, is the return statement that is returning the data.  This is being returned from a .NET MVC application.  I added in the UTF8 when that was mentioned and still get the same error.

```
return Json(data: new { Response = returnValue }, contentType: "application/json", contentEncoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, behavior: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And the entire error message:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"Response":{"ReturnCode":200,"ReturnMessage":"Information Successfully Retrieved","ReturnData":null,"ReturnClass":{"PRO_ID":"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111","PRO_FirstName":"Silver","PRO_LastName":"HIYO"},"FriendlyErrorMessage":null}} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 1):

> type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

This means "Use getString() for String"
getJSONObject() may cause this error.

```
class Response {
    String returnMessage;
    ...
}    

Response response;
response.returnMessage= "msg";

JSONObjct obj;
obj = response.getJSONObject("ReturnMessage"); // cannot be converted
```

---

It maybe a encoding problem. Browser (and source editor) may have converted the result string encoding.

> Q: ... I am storing items for the JSON data as Strings which is resulting in some odd character appearing
>   A: new String(jo.getString("name").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");

[Android JSON CharSet UTF-8 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069799/android-json-charset-utf-8-problems)

---

Hard coded JSON string is valid. If you want to try, replace (\") with (") and paste it to the checker.

```
{
    "Response": {
        "ReturnCode": 200,
        "ReturnMessage": "Information Successfully Retrieved",
        "ReturnData": null,
        "ReturnClass": {
            "PRO_ID": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
            "PRO_FirstName": "SILVER",
            "PRO_LastName": "HIYO"
        },
        "FriendlyErrorMessage": null
    }
}
```

JSON object is like a structure (or class)
It looks like this.

```
class Response {
    int ReturnCode = 200;
    String ReturnMessage = "Information Successfully Retrieved";
    ...
}
```

---

Sample code.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONObject response;
    int returnCode;
    String returnMessage;
    //JSONObject returnMessage;

    result = "{\"Response\":{\"ReturnCode\":200,\"ReturnMessage\":\"Information Successfully Retrieved\",\"ReturnData\":null,\"ReturnClass\":{\"PRO_ID\":\"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111\",\"PRO_FirstName\":\"SILVER\",\"PRO_LastName\":\"HIYO\"},\"FriendlyErrorMessage\":null}}";
    try
    {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        response = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Response");
        returnCode = response.getInt("ReturnCode");
        returnMessage = response.getString("ReturnMessage");
        //returnMessage = response.getJSONObject("ReturnMessage"); // This may cause same error
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't even get to the point of referencing a value within the created JSON object.  This bombs on the initial creation of the JSON object itself.

Comment: Please check the JSON string that you have hard coded. It is invalid, you can check for its validity at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The Json string is valid and I already used json lint.  If it wasn't a valid string, than the hard coded string wouldn't work which it does.

Comment: All the stuff you have there is really what I have in my ApiMethods class.  All of the Api calls return a similare structure which is a ReturnMessage class that contains a return code, friendly message, another message for success or failure, a ReturnClass which is basically the class object being returned and than ReturnData is a list string that returns information that was passed in.   So all the code you are showing I have built.  As I said it works completely fine hard coded just not with the string being passed in which looks fine when I step through while debugging.

Comment: I even made sure to return the api call so it would use UTF-8 and still no go.  `return Json(data: new { Response = returnValue }, contentType: "application/json", contentEncoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, behavior: JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`   This is data returned from a .NET MVC application.

Comment: I see your error message. It means "Use getString() for String." If you use getJSONObject() for String, it causes the error.

Comment: How can I use the getJSONObject if my code is bombing when I am trying to create the initial JSONObject value?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your hardcoded json object is not a valid json object. This may be the reason why it throws exception. Check validitiy of json object [here](http://jsonlint.com/) first.

Comment: The result is valid, once you remove the \".  That was done for escape character reasons within the string.  I checked it with lint.  If the hard coded result wasn't valid json than it wouldn't work, which it does.

Answer (score 0):

Use this site to validate your json string

***http://jsonlint.com/***